# SUM and Count in one SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, sum

I have this kind of data

```
time                                               Members
-------------------------------------------------- -----------
Jun 23 2016                                           1
Jun 23 2016                                           1
Jun 23 2016                                           2
Jun 29 2016                                           6
Jul 11 2016                                           3
Jul 11 2016                                           1
Jul 13 2016                                           1
```

I obtained this data using this sql query

```
SELECT CONVERT (VARCHAR(12), a.registered_time), COUNT(b.member_id) AS Members
FROM b
Inner JOIN a ON b.mirror_id = a.mirror_id 
GROUP BY 
(a.registered_time) order by a.registered_time
```

I want to get the sum of total numbers if they are of the same date for exampple the date of June 23 2016 will have total members of 4 and so on. Is it possible to have SUM() FUnction on Count()? How can I do this?

Comment: Count of menberid itself give you the 4 for that date,  no need of sum again there,  and convert registered date also to date in group by

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the value to a `date` and include that in both the `select` and `group by`:

```
SELECT CONVERT(date, a.registered_time) as dte, COUNT(b.member_id) AS Members
FROM b JOIN
     a
     ON b.mirror_id = a.mirror_id 
GROUP BY CONVERT(date, a.registered_time)
ORDER BY CONVERT(date, a.registered_time);
```

Comment: Returns me an error that registered_time is invalid in ORDER BY because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @bleykFaust . . . That should be the expression or `dte`.

Comment: How about I I only want to get the year for the time?

Comment: @bleykFaust . . . You would use `year()` or `datepart()` or `datename()`.